# tricky css: 3 sections in a row, all 3 can be variable width

Tags: html, css

check this out

http://jsfiddle.net/38Hmp/

The dom structure is this

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="left">aaa</div>
    <div class="middle">middlemiddlemiddlemiddlemiddlemiddle</div>
    <div class="right">bbb</div>
</div>
```

1. outer is fixed width,
2. left and right to be on the left and right, respectively
3. all three sections contain variable width content.

The middle section should not overflow or push the right section out of the container.

Ideally the middle would have ellipses in the event of overflow.

I can't see how to avoid pushing the right section out in the event of long middle section without a max width, but that kills the variable width of the right section.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Can the 'variable lengths' of .right and .left be in percentages?

Comment: nope, they need to get as big as they need to get, the middle section is what shrinks if necessary

Comment: That doesn't make sense, how could they be "as big as needed"? If the outer is fixed width you'll have overflow and without some minimum width, every else wouldn't know what size to start

Comment: Without js or dimension measurements you're likely stuck with flexbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found a pure css solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/38Hmp/2/

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="left">aaa</div>    
    <div class="right">bbb</div>    
    <div class="middle">middlemiddlemiddlemiddlemiddlemiddle</div>
</div>
```

left and right both float (left and right) and middle has no float.

Its key that left and right go into the dom before middle.

css

```
.outer {
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 20px;
    width: 200px;
}

.left {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.middle {
     overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.right {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use flexbox?

It has the properties you need. Setting the growth property to 0 & shrink property to 1, perhaps?

```
-webkit-box-flex: 0;
-moz-box-flex: 0;
-webkit-flex: 0 1 auto;
-ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
flex: 0 1 auto;
```

And maybe you could play with it, [here](http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/?fixed-height=on&legacy=on&display=flex&flex-direction=row&flex-wrap=nowrap&justify-content=flex-start&align-items=center&align-content=flex-start&order%5B%5D=0&flex-grow%5B%5D=0&flex-shrink%5B%5D=0&flex-basis%5B%5D=auto&align-self%5B%5D=auto&order%5B%5D=0&flex-grow%5B%5D=0&flex-shrink%5B%5D=1&flex-basis%5B%5D=auto&align-self%5B%5D=auto&order%5B%5D=0&flex-grow%5B%5D=0&flex-shrink%5B%5D=0&flex-basis%5B%5D=auto&align-self%5B%5D=auto).

Comment: ill have to look at this; I am unfamiliar.  We are not using grandma's browser, so it might be ok

Answer (score 0):

Incomplete but it can get you started

html

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="left">aaa</div>
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="right">bbb</div>
        <div class="middle">middlemiddlemiddlemiddlemiddlemiddle</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.outer {
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 20px;
    width: 200px;
}

.left {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}
.inner {
    float: right;
}
.middle {
    float:left;
    display: inline-block; 
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.right {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: it seems that the contents of the middle section are tied to the right, not to the left.   Is that the case?

Comment: Do you want it on the left instead?

Comment: yeah, wasn't in my original question but that is another condition

Comment: Put .inner around .left and .middle||float right .right, .middle || float left .left